# tensorflow periodic padding

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow I cannot find a straightforward possibility to do a convolution ([tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d)) with periodic boundary conditions.

E.g. take the tensor

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

and any 3x3 filter. A convolution with periodic boundary conditions could in principle be done by doing a periodic padding to 5x5

```
[[9,7,8,9,7],
 [3,1,2,3,1],
 [6,4,5,6,4],
 [9,7,8,9,7],
 [3,1,2,3,1]]
```

and subsequently a convolution with the filter in "valid" mode. However, the function [tf.pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad) unfortunately does not support periodic padding.

Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 5):

The following should work for your case :

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = tf.tile(a, [3, 3])
result = b[2:7, 2:7]
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(result.eval())

# prints the following 
array([[9, 7, 8, 9, 7],
       [3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [6, 4, 5, 6, 4],
       [9, 7, 8, 9, 7],
       [3, 1, 2, 3, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

As noted in the comments, this is a little inefficient in terms of memory. If memory is an issue for you, but are willing to spend some compute, the following will also work :

```
pre = tf.constant([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
post = tf.transpose(pre)
result = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(pre, a), post)
print(result.eval())
```

Comment: Many Thanks! Works fine (except that it should be result.eval()). However, this seems a bit inefficient to me if "a" is large and the filter is small. Or is tensorflow able to figure out that it does not actually need to compute all components of b?

Comment: Sorry about the typo, fixed it. Yes, this method is inefficient, as it creates 9 copies of the images and throws away most of them. TensorFlow currently doesn't have the optimization that would compute `result` without materializing `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more general and flexible: periodic padding for one or more specified axes, with optionally specifiyng different padding lenghts for different axes

```
import tensorflow as tf

def periodic_padding_flexible(tensor, axis,padding=1):
    """
        add periodic padding to a tensor for specified axis
        tensor: input tensor
        axis: on or multiple axis to pad along, int or tuple
        padding: number of cells to pad, int or tuple

        return: padded tensor
    """


    if isinstance(axis,int):
        axis = (axis,)
    if isinstance(padding,int):
        padding = (padding,)

    ndim = len(tensor.shape)
    for ax,p in zip(axis,padding):
        # create a slice object that selects everything from all axes,
        # except only 0:p for the specified for right, and -p: for left

        ind_right = [slice(-p,None) if i == ax else slice(None) for i in range(ndim)]
        ind_left = [slice(0, p) if i == ax else slice(None) for i in range(ndim)]
        right = tensor[ind_right]
        left = tensor[ind_left]
        middle = tensor
        tensor = tf.concat([right,middle,left], axis=ax)

    return tensor



a = tf.constant([
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

result = periodic_padding_flexible(a, axis=1,padding=1)
print('a:')
print(a.eval())
print('padded a:')
print(result.eval())

result = periodic_padding_flexible(a, axis=2,padding=1)
print('a:')
print(a.eval())
print('padded a:')
print(result.eval())

result = periodic_padding_flexible(a, axis=(1,2),padding=(1,2))
print('a:')
print(a.eval())
print('padded a:')
print(result.eval())
```

output:

```
a:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]
 [[11 12 13]
  [14 15 16]
  [17 18 19]]]
padded a:
[[[ 7  8  9]
  [ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [ 1  2  3]]
 [[17 18 19]
  [11 12 13]
  [14 15 16]
  [17 18 19]
  [11 12 13]]]
a:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]
 [[11 12 13]
  [14 15 16]
  [17 18 19]]]
padded a:
[[[ 3  1  2  3  1]
  [ 6  4  5  6  4]
  [ 9  7  8  9  7]]
 [[13 11 12 13 11]
  [16 14 15 16 14]
  [19 17 18 19 17]]]
a:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]
 [[11 12 13]
  [14 15 16]
  [17 18 19]]]
padded a:
[[[ 8  9  7  8  9  7  8]
  [ 2  3  1  2  3  1  2]
  [ 5  6  4  5  6  4  5]
  [ 8  9  7  8  9  7  8]
  [ 2  3  1  2  3  1  2]]
 [[18 19 17 18 19 17 18]
  [12 13 11 12 13 11 12]
  [15 16 14 15 16 14 15]
  [18 19 17 18 19 17 18]
  [12 13 11 12 13 11 12]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of periodic padding in tensorflow that works for a batch of 2-dimensional images. It uses slices and tf.concat:

```
def periodic_padding(x, padding=1):
    '''
    x: shape (batch_size, d1, d2)
    return x padded with periodic boundaries. i.e. torus or donut
    '''
    d1 = x.shape[1] # dimension 1: height
    d2 = x.shape[2] # dimension 2: width
    p = padding
    # assemble padded x from slices
    #            tl,tc,tr
    # padded_x = ml,mc,mr
    #            bl,bc,br
    top_left = x[:, -p:, -p:] # top left
    top_center = x[:, -p:, :] # top center
    top_right = x[:, -p:, :p] # top right
    middle_left = x[:, :, -p:] # middle left
    middle_center = x # middle center
    middle_right = x[:, :, :p] # middle right
    bottom_left = x[:, :p, -p:] # bottom left
    bottom_center = x[:, :p, :] # bottom center
    bottom_right = x[:, :p, :p] # bottom right
    top = tf.concat([top_left, top_center, top_right], axis=2)
    middle = tf.concat([middle_left, middle_center, middle_right], axis=2)
    bottom = tf.concat([bottom_left, bottom_center, bottom_right], axis=2)
    padded_x = tf.concat([top, middle, bottom], axis=1)
    return padded_x

import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
])
result = periodic_padding(a, padding=1)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print('a:')
print(a.eval())
print('padded a:')
print(result.eval())
sess.close()
```

The output of the example is:

```
a:
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[11 12 13]
  [14 15 16]
  [17 18 19]]]
padded a:
[[[ 9  7  8  9  7]
  [ 3  1  2  3  1]
  [ 6  4  5  6  4]
  [ 9  7  8  9  7]
  [ 3  1  2  3  1]]

 [[19 17 18 19 17]
  [13 11 12 13 11]
  [16 14 15 16 14]
  [19 17 18 19 17]
  [13 11 12 13 11]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation first adds periodic padding on the left and right, which increases the number of columns, and thus, just by further copying the npad number of rows at the upper and bottom, it achieves periodic padding.
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

```
def PeriodicPad(a, npad=1):
    '''
    a   : [i,j,k] the padding will be applied for [j,k]
    npad: width of padding 
    '''
    L = a[:,:, -npad:    ]
    R = a[:,:,      :npad]   

    a = tf.concat([L,a,R],axis=2) 

    U = a[:, -npad:     , :]
    B = a[:,      :npad , :]  

    a = tf.concat([U,a,B],axis=1) 

    return a

a = tf.Variable(np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3), dtype=tf.float32)
b = PeriodicPad(a)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 3, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14.],
        [15., 16., 17.]]], dtype=float32)>
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 8.  6.  7.  8.  6.]
  [ 2.  0.  1.  2.  0.]
  [ 5.  3.  4.  5.  3.]
  [ 8.  6.  7.  8.  6.]
  [ 2.  0.  1.  2.  0.]]

 [[17. 15. 16. 17. 15.]
  [11.  9. 10. 11.  9.]
  [14. 12. 13. 14. 12.]
  [17. 15. 16. 17. 15.]
  [11.  9. 10. 11.  9.]]], shape=(2, 5, 5), dtype=float32)
```